# Same Result is getting override When executing multiple requests using Parallel.Foreach

Tags: parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Problem: Same Result is getting override When executing multiple requests using Parallel.Foreach

I am continuously accepting requests and launching a new task for each request using Task Factory and then using `Parallel.Foreach()` to execute these requests on multiple processor (as per the code's logic)

--First launching each request using task.factory
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessProcessorsInParallel(e.ConfigKey, content));

--Second execution begin here ,each request are getting executed using parallel.foreach and here p.result is getting override for multile requests ,getting same result(p.result) which is incorrect.

```
    private void ProcessProcessorsInParallel(string configkey, string content)
    {  
       var processes = GetFLProcessor().Processors.Where(p => p.Enabled).ToList();
        Parallel.ForEach(processes, (p) =>
        {
            p.Process(content, configkey);
            var p1 = new PB();
          var result = CheckResponse.ParseFrom(Base64.decodeBase64(p.Result));
         }
    }
```

Should i use lock inside the parallel.foreach? If yes how i can achieve parallelism?

Here Result(p.Result) property is getting set Process method and we are trying to access Result proeperty after this Process method call. For mulitples request, Result is getting same from multiples request.

Processor class and Process Method details are mentioned below:

```
public  class Processor
  {

 public string Result
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


 public void Process(string inputTrade, string key)
    {

     Result = RuleChecker.Check(inputTrade, new List<Type>() { 'ABC" }, previousTradeXml).ToByteString().ToBase64();

    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are trying to access the Result property?

Answer (score 0):

If there is any scope of parallelizing the processing, then parallelism is already achieved when you are attempting to do a Parallel.Foreach(). However, your answer will be correct (i.e. will match the answer of serial execution) only if you allow only one thread to enter the critical section of the code at a time.

To attain this mutual exclusion, you will have to use locks over the shared resources. These shared resources may not be limited to a data structure, but could even be your monitor if, for example, you are printing something on the screen.

Update your question further if you want a more specific answer.